# Why this didn't work if i use get_the_ID(), but works if i pass the numeric id

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, uploads

It is a custom meta box that handles pdf upload. I want to get the URL of the uploaded file. Inside admin, it works but on the homepage, it doesn't work.

```
function moin_notifications_get() {
        // Get the 'Profiles' post type
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'mmi-notification',
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        $file = get_post_meta(the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true);
            echo '<ul class="moin-notifications">';
        while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();  
            echo '<li class="moin-note-single"><a href="'. $file['url'] .'">'. get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        endwhile;
            echo '</ul>';
        wp_reset_query();
    }
```

The following way it will work.

```
get_post_meta('6211', 'wp_custom_attachment', true);
```

Any idea, where I am doing the wrong thing. The problem is with the id.

**Edit:**
Earlier I used `get_the_ID()` and that didn't work.

Solved:
This is the correct way to do this. Thank Tom

```
function moin_notifications_get() { // Get the 'Profiles' post type
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'mmi-notification',
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    
    echo '<ul class="moin-notifications">';
    while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
        $file = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true);
        echo '<li class="moin-note-single"><a href="'. $file['url'] .'">'. get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: `the_ID` is for displaying the ID, not retrieving the ID, its usage inside `get_post_meta` is incorrect. I also notice you used it outside the loop, not inside the loop, this doesn't make sense as the loop hasn't changed the current post yet, and every single item in the loop would have the same value. Also `wp_reset_query` is intended for cleaning up after a `query_posts` call but there is no such call. Use `wp_reset_postdata()` instead

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't pay attention to the loop. Anyways, thanks for your help, it worked.